# R language, keras, parallel computation

Tags: r, keras, parallel-processing

Although I modeled on a 40-core computer, I only used a few of them when modeling with Keras. I would like to know how to call all CPU cores for computation. I tried to implement parallel computing in the following way but failed. Scholars, please enlighten me on other methods.

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)
history <- model %>% fit(xtrain, ytrain,
                                     epochs = 200, batch_size=100, verbose = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow/Keras takes care of parallelism in `fit()`, and it generally won't work if you manually try to fork the parent R process or manage a PSOCK cluster. The {parallel} package that comes with R is not compatible with Tensorflow/Keras.

If it looks like Tensorflow/Keras is not using all your CPU cores with the default settings, you can adjust the thread pool size here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/threading (but, in my experience, it's more likely that you're IO-limited, or the CPU is waiting on the GPU, and probably not that the thread pool size is too small).

If you're interested in distributed computing with Tensorflow, here is a good place to get started: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute

Comment: I have another question that I would like to ask you to teach you. If a neural network model with multiple outputs is built using the keras package in R, is the correlation between the output neurons of the multi-output neural network model considered?

Comment: I have the above doubts about whether to consider the correlation between the output neurons of the multi-output deep neural network, please answer. Thank you in advance.